# Possible to integrate xsl into xml

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, linq-to-xml

I am using XDocument to create an xml file which uses an xsl file as a stylesheet.  I want to make the xml downloadable which I have no problem with but the issue I have is that I have two files when I only want one file download.

I use the following to include the link:

```
doc.AddFirst(new XProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='Stylesheet.XSL'"));
```

Is it possible to merge the xsl file into the XDocument object?

EDIT:
Found I can do this:

```
XDocument transformedDoc = new XDocument();
        using (XmlWriter writer = transformedDoc.CreateWriter())
        {
            XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            transform.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XML/CareLog.xsl"))));
            transform.Transform(doc.CreateReader(), writer);
        }
        transformedDoc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/BrowserTemp/CareLog.xml"));
```

But I get the error "data at the root level is invalid" on the transform.Load() line? Anything I need to look out for?

Comment: I don't think so , XML itself has no logic of processing hence we use an XSL for tranforming an XML.

Comment: What about using PDFSharp or MigraDoc to somehow open the xml with the link and produce a pdf??

Comment: Sorry I believe I haven't understood the requirement correctly , When you said 2 files - Is it the xsl and xml ?

Comment: Yes, can I output the file as a html file or something so I end up with a single file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from the standard ... simple example but embeds style sheet inside the XML:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Embedding-Stylesheets

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="#style1"?>
<doc>
<head>
<xsl:stylesheet id="style1"
            version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="id('foo')">
<fo:block font-weight="bold"><xsl:apply-templates/></fo:block>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet">
 <!-- ignore -->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</head>
<body>
<para id="foo">
...
</para>
</body>
</doc>
```